# Close "Date and Time Picker" by Enter or Button inside the Picker

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

does anybody know if there is a solution to show a save button at the date and time picker? users hab problems, when there is no save button after choosing a time and date

Answer (score 0):

Save as in "Recompute":
I believe you could add a button ("Save") and tell it to recompute variables you want to update.

Save as in "Persist Selection":
I don't think so but you can define a default in the workshop editor.
The default could be relative. I usually have a default of like:
3 days ago - Indefinitely

To do the latter you'll need to:

1. go into Editor Mode
2. Click on your widget
3. Under Output Data > Filter Output click on the variable (or create one)
4. Select your object type/set
5. Add Filter
6. Pick your date column
7. Toggle "Relative to Today"
8. pick whatever makes most sense in your case
9. Save + Publish your Workshop

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The idea is to give the user a visible way to close the picker. This closes itself if you click another area in the module, but some users experienced irritation during testing because they were looking for a save button.

Comment: you could put it in a "section" and turn on "COLLAPSIBLE".
Then add a button which triggers event: "Close Section"